# Can we attach a new Application Target Group to existing AutoScaling Group?

Tags: python, aws-cdk

Is there a way to attach a new Application Target Group to existing AutoScaling Group?

In my code below I am trying to attempt it but it did not seem to work.

```
lb = aws_cdk.aws_elasticloadbalancingv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(self, "ServiceApplicationLB", vpc=vpc, internet_facing=True, security_group=sg)

#Fetching AutoScalingGroup ID from Service Stack
AsgNameOutputs = boto3.Session().client("cloudformation").describe_stacks(StackName="Service")["Stacks"][0]["Outputs"]
AsgNames=[]

for Output in AsgNameOutputs:
    if Output["OutputKey"].startswith("AutoScalingGroupName"):
        AsgNames.append(Output["OutputValue"])

print("AsgNames: ", AsgNames)

listener = lb.add_listener("Listener", port=80)

applicationTargetGroup = listener.add_targets("Target", port=8080,
    health_check={"path": "/ping", "interval": Duration.seconds(30), "port": "8080"})

for AsgName in AsgNames:
    asg = aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup.from_auto_scaling_group_name(self, AsgName, auto_scaling_group_name=AsgName)     # FIX ME
    #Above line is returning IAutoScalingGroup. Instead I need AutoScalingGroup here so to call the attach_to_application_target_group method

    aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup.attach_to_application_target_group(asg, target_group=applicationTargetGroup)    #FIX ME
```

Comment: `attach_to_application_target_group` is not a static method on AutoScalingGroup. It is a public method available on the object itself. So I believe you should try using `asg. attach_to_application_target_group()`. Please check documentation here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/python/aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling/AutoScalingGroup.html#aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup.attach_to_application_target_group

Comment: I tried with:
asg.attach_to_application_target_group(target_group=applicationTargetGroup)


Still getting the same error :

AttributeError: '<class 'aws_cdk.core.Resource'>+<class 'aws_cdk.aws_autoscaling._IAutoScalingGroupProxy'>' object has no attribute 'attach_to_application_target_group'

I think problem is one line above 
asg = autoscaling.AutoScalingGroup.from_auto_scaling_group_name(self, AsgName, auto_scaling_group_name=AsgName)

which is returning IAutoScalingGroupProxy object instead I need AutoScalingGroup object.

How can I get that not sure!

Comment: Ahh.. I see what is going on after I dove deep in the ASG CDK code. Will let you know if there is a way

Comment: Interesting problem.. I have not been able to find a work around yet. Will keep you posted if I do.

Comment: @dmahapatro Sure thanks!

Comment: At this moment it is not possible to import a resource to CDK and use some of the methods to change the resource. I spent half of the day today diving deep as well as consulting with other people. :) I believe you have to use boto3 again (as done earlier) to attach ASG to Application Target Group. Great question, it allowed me to understand more as to how CDK works. +1